# how do I save a part of a variable string?

Tags: android, string, variables, response

I get a response but it's different for every user.
I want to extract the UserID & Name. How can I do this?

The response String:

```
{
    "sessionkey":"f4b54dedlfkjhgdlfkjghdfslkjgh1a255242bf71597f4b35ac882f0702",
    "user" : {
        "userID" : "1",
        "name":"Test"
    }
}
```

I want to save 1 = (String userid)
and save Test = (String name)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.androhub.com/android-json-parser/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a simple JSON blob, so use a JSON Parser to extract the data.

My lib of choice is [`org.json.json`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json).

```
String blob = "{ origin string }";

// create a new json object from the main blob
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(blob);

// extract the session key
String sessionKey = root.getString("sessionkey");

// extract the user object
JSONObject user = root.getJSONObject("user");

// extract the user id
String userId = user.getString("userID");
```

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for the quick reply! How do I add this lib? I see what you did with the code, it's just not accepting it.

Comment: If you are using maven, add the dependency blob. If you are not using maven, download the jar and add it to your classpath. I've linked to the artifact at mvncentral.